# Formatting Decimals to specific number of Decimal Places

Tags: fable-f#

See here
Not this is specific to Fable - it works fine with the .NET runtime
https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/issues/2276
Any help / input / ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had written a function for this purpose

```fsharp
type Floating =
    | Fix of byte
    | Sci of byte
    | Norm

let strFormat precision value =
    match precision with
    | Fix x -> 
        sprintf 
            (Printf.StringFormat<decimal -> string>
                ("%+." + sprintf "%i" x + "f"))
            value
    | Sci x ->
        sprintf
            (Printf.StringFormat<int -> string>
                (sprintf
                    (Printf.StringFormat<float -> string>
                        ("%+." + sprintf "%if" x))
                    ((float value) / 10.0 ** (value |> float |> log10 |> floor))
                + "E%i"))
            (value |> float |> log10 |> int)
    | Norm ->
        let x =
            let l = (string value).Split('.')
            match l.Length with
            | 2 -> l.[1].Length
            | _ -> 0
        sprintf
            (Printf.StringFormat<decimal -> string>
                ("%+." + sprintf "%i" x + "f"))
            value
```